# FTDI device draining battery of Android device

Tags: android, kotlin, usb, ftdi

I'm currently developing a mobile app that communicates with an external FTDI USB-C device. I use a device filter with the vendor and product ID to automatically open the application when the device is connected. The serial communication is done using Android's UsbManager and other native communication classes. The problem I'm having is that the battery life of the smartphone changed drastically. The autonomy of the Samsung Galaxy A50 is usually somewhere between 3 to 4 days. With the FTDI device attached, the autonomy is reduced to 1 day. After communicating with the FTDI device, I make sure that all connections (UsbManager, UsbDeviceConnection...) are closed. Is there anything I can do here to improve battery life of the smartphone?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If the device does not have it's own power supply and is dependent on the phone's battery then there is hardly anything you can do to improve battery life.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! The FTDI device has its own power supply, it is a secondary device.

Comment: Is it designed to be self-powered as well? This is a matter of the schematic/circuit. Did you measure the current e.g. using one of those plugs which show the usb voltage and current?

Comment: Yes, the device is self-powered, it has its own battery. The device turns on when it detects a smartphone connected to it. At first, I tried to make the FTDI device the primary device, providing the smartphone with power. But then ofcourse whenever we connected the FTDI device the smartphone would say that it is charging and I didn't want that. So now the FTDI device provides a small charge at the USB bus just to be detected by the smartphone, nothing more.